# Angular.js problems with small numbers and scientific notation in input fields

Tags: angularjs

I'm having troubles displaying and editing small numbers in an input field using Angular.js v1.3.14.

I've attempted to use a directive to prevent the number from displaying in scientific notation. example: 0.00000005 instead of 5e-8.

I get an error message from the directive because the datatype returned is a string and not a number.

This is the error message I receive: `Error: [ngModel:numfmt] Expected '0.00000005' to be a number`

HTML:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="number" ng-model="myNum" />
    <br/>
    <input decimal type="number" ng-model="myNum" />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.myNum = 0.00000005;
    })
    .directive('decimal', function()
    {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {

                ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data) 
                {
                    var newData = data.toFixed != null ? data.toFixed(8) : data;

                    console.log('data', data, newData);
                    //convert data from model format to view format
                    return newData; //converted
                });

            }
        };
    });
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joelnet/u277z929

note: Ideally I would prefer to use type="number" and not type="text" for the input field.

How can I force the input field to display ONLY decimal and not the scientific notation?

EDIT: The reason I prefer to use type="number" is because (1) the field is a number type. (2) this brings up the number pad on mobile. (3) I can use the min, max fields. (4) The $scope.$watch only fires when the number is valid. (5) it's cleaner.

EDIT2: It appears FireFox displays correctly (and doesn't need the directive example: http://jsfiddle.net/joelnet/u277z929/7), while Chrome and Internet Explorer display the number as scientific notation. Both of the input fields should display the number as decimal and never as scientific notation.

Comment: I think the only way is change number to text?

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/u277z929/6/

Comment: @Tony, no, I want the number to be displayed as a decimal.

Comment: @joelnet It is? Where exactly do you want it "displayed"? Or possibly more importantly, what browser are you using?

Comment: It appears FireFox displays correctly, while Chrome and Internet Explorer display the number as scientific notation. Both of the input fields should display the number as decimal and never as scientific notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AngularJS documentation for `input[number]` [specifically says](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D):

> The model must always be of type number otherwise Angular will throw an error. Be aware that a string containing a number is not enough. See the numfmt error docs for more information and an example of how to convert your model if necessary.

You can read more information on the `numfmt` [error documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/numfmt).
As far as I can tell, there is no way to do this while specifying `type="number"`. The last item that must go through the `$formatters` array must return a number, not a string.

If you change to `type="text"`, your code will work fine:

```
<input decimal type="text" ng-model="myNum" />
```

What is your motivation for using `type=number`? If you're looking to only allow numerical entry, you can use `pattern` or a directive to create that behaviour.

Comment: The reason I prefer to use type="number" is because (1) the field is a number type. (2) this brings up the number pad on mobile. (3) I can use the min, max fields. (4) The $scope.$watch only fires when the number is valid. (5) it's cleaner.

Comment: @joelnet the cross browser support for doing that isn't there yet, this won't be possible without hackery. If you apply the correct `pattern` limiter, mobile devices will show the numeric keyboard by default, and the rest of the behaviour can be implemented as a directive. I think that's you're best bet!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you can't change the displayed format of the input `type="number"`.

There are plenty  libraries for formatting scientific notations into javascript, but what are you trying to do you will have to create a directive.

Using two inputs, and one of them visible which displays the non-scientific notation and is bind to the normal number-input. I don't know if this is cleaner enough for you requirement. [Here i made](http://plnkr.co/edit/OSQWLO?p=preview) you an example

Answer (score 0):

Based on your fiddle, you can have an `<input type="number">` field that validates on 0.00000005 by making these changes:

```
<input decimal type="number" ng-model="myNum" step="any" />
```

and

```
return Number(newData); //converted
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/u277z929/6/

Comment: No, I want the number to display as a decimal and not as scientific notation.

Comment: It appears FireFox displays correctly, while Chrome and Internet Explorer display the number as scientific notation. Both of the input fields should display the number as decimal and never as scientific notation.

Comment: The only browsers I have access to right now are IE9 and FF31, and both of these work for me. In IE you have to type into the input, it won't display by default. This is most likely a case of browsers behind the standard. More [here](https://blog.isotoma.com/2012/03/html5-input-typenumber-and-decimalsfloats-in-chrome/).

Comment: I'm using FireFox 35.01, 11.0.9600.17691 and Chrome 41.0.2272.118. I believe in your example, instead of adding `Number()` to the return you can just remove the directive completely. example: http://jsfiddle.net/joelnet/u277z929/7

Comment: My browser still requires `step="any"` to validate, otherwise I agree. Cross-browser support is so fun...